# Add constant to array

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I have this code:

```
const int a = 2;

const int arr[] = {
  1,a,3,4
};
```

But it gives me this error:

> source.c:6:3: error: initializer element is not constant

How can I add a constant to an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const int is not considered a constant.

You will have to use the actual number or define it.

```
#define FOUR 4

const int arr[] = {
   1,FOUR,3,4 
};
```

Using compound literals, it is possible to initialize it with variables:

```
const int value = 2 ;

const int *array[] = { &(int){1} , &value , &(int){3} , &(int){4} } ;

int main(void){

    printf("%d" , *array[1] ) ;

  return 0;
}
```

Unnamed objects used to initialize array( `(int){1}` ) have file scope and static storage duration.

Comment: `const int` is considered a "constant variable", while numbers are considered "const numbers" or just constants. For gcc it works with constant variables/typedef though. Some old compilers also won't compile your compound literals example.

Comment: You can also use an enum.  `enum { FOUR = 4 };`

Comment: @user139873 Yes and it is supposed to use less memory.

Comment: @Edenia c Standard doesn't allow that; 6.7.9: *All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
shall be constant expressions or string literals.* What is a constant, 6.4.4: *Constants* About the pre c99 compilers; If OP required an example that conforms to 15 years old standard, the he would specify it( tag ). I think the accepted answer speaks for itself. Is the downvote really warranted?

Comment: @Edenia: I don't know what you mean by "constant variable"; the C standard certainly doesn't use that term. The keyword `const` is best thought of as "read-only". The standard uses the term "constant" to refer to an expression that can (and in many cases must) be evaluated at compile time (or perhaps at link time for address constants).

Comment: @user139873: The enum hack is great -- but it's limited to constants of type `int`.

Comment: @self on C89 Works well. %Keith Thompson right, well.. country translations and terms are being illogical sometimes.

Comment: Compound literals are such strange things.

Comment: How is using `enum` a "hack"? It's not :)